# CSP Browser Policy + Zopim widget (+ underscore)

Tags: meteor, content-security-policy

For the past few days, I've been trying to add properly Meteor's CSP package, browser-policy. So far, I followed these ressources:

- https://dweldon.silvrback.com/browser-policy
- https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-the-browser-policy-package/

Things were a bit rough at the beginning but we are close to something, the last piece of the puzzle being live-chat Zopim's widget not being a fan of our new policy. I tried to whitelist and put zopim's widget code into a `Meteor.startup` call somewhere but it still fails on load due to some `unsafe-eval` as you can see below.
[image: Zopim's errors on load with browser policy]

As I don't want to loosen up more my policies, is there any workaround for this or should I just forget about Zopim and give a shot at some other tool (which I'd be glad to hear about if you have any suggestion).

**Bonus:** Also, I first had my policy with `BrowserPolicy.content.disallowEval();` but MDG's `underscore` package started to fall appart and I had to allow it. Allowing eval is clearly not ideal and I'd be glad to hear any alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Your're hitting the first bullet point from the "issues" section of my post. You have to decide if disallowing `eval` is more important to you than that particular 3rd party script. In our case, we allowed `eval` for a few days while the external script was modified (fortunately the creator agreed to the change). It never hurts to send an email and just explain that you think their scripts are posing a risk to your site because you can't enable a strict content security policy.

We currently have `BrowserPolicy.content.disallowEval()` set and haven't run into any issues. I find it hard to believe that a core package would violate that directive. Maybe some other package is causing it, but it's hard to say without a detailed analysis of your dependencies.

Comment: Hey David, really glad you found my question. As for Zopim, I have little hope about getting their team to address the problem any time soon given [this ticket](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203348317-JS-library-uses-eval-breaks-sane-CSP-config). Concerning underscore, you are certainly right, underscore.js:1287 popped up in my console but it might be caused by some use of it by other dependencies I use. It makes me wonder how other Meteor devs do with their CSP.